UPDATE multiple rows and plus two row in one query
How can I update multiple rows in one query?
UPDATE table SET col_1=col_1+5, col_2=col_2+7 WHERE id=12;
UPDATE table SET col_1=col_1+2, col_2=col_2+6 WHERE id=16
...
UPDATE table SET col_1=col_1+..., col_2=col_2+... WHERE id=...

How to union following queries

Therse are different statements. You need to call each of them.

More important is why you want to do this so that we can help best address the actual underlying issue.

This is an XY Problem. Why do you want to run them all as a single query? Isn't it better to batch the updates?

This is an [XY Problem[(https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you want to run them all at once? Isn't it better to batch them?

Here's a way to do it:
WITH cte(id, col1, col2) AS (
  VALUES ROW(12, 5, 7), ROW(16, 2, 6), ROW(20, 1, 4)
)
UPDATE mytable
JOIN cte USING (id)
SET mytable.col1 = mytable.col1 + cte.col1,
    mytable.col2 = mytable.col2 + cte.col2;

WITH and the VALUES statement requires MySQL 8.0.
Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/DQ_g6CZg

If this is about considering the updates as an atomic action that shall be committed or rolled back, then wrap them in a transaction:
START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE table SET col_1=col_1+5, col_2=col_2+7 WHERE id=12;
UPDATE table SET col_1=col_1+2, col_2=col_2+6 WHERE id=16
...
COMMIT;

If this is about avoiding round trips by sending one combined statement to the server instead of single statements, one after the other, then combine them:
UPDATE table 
SET col_1 = col_1 + CASE WHEN id = 12 THEN 5 WHEN id = 16 THEN 2 WHEN id = ... END
  , col_2 = col_2 + CASE WHEN id = 12 THEN 7 WHEN id = 16 THEN 6 WHEN id = ... END
WHERE id  IN (12, 16, ...);

